# C# Search Using ComboBox and TextBox (Access Database)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, textbox

(First of all...... Sorry to my english :D)
I already post my problem here [c# Search using ComboBox and Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893035/c-sharp-search-using-combobox-and-textbox/34893177#34893177) .. no one solved my problem but I used their codes to simplify my codes.

When I started the program the `DataGridView` looks so normal.. I choose a field in `ComboBox` and type in `TextBox`.. the results showed but the problem is.... their's another column that added to the `DataGridView` and it's empty... I want you to help me to remove that column

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc9AQ.jpg) (I am new here in stackoverflow.. I dont have enough reputation to post images)

```
public void searchData()
{
    string sql = "Select ID,Quantity,Unit,ItemCode,ItemName,Cbm,TotalCbm from Inventory Order By ID asc;";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        string value = cboFields.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
            @"Select ID,      
            Quantity,Unit,ItemCode,ItemName,Cbm,TotalCbm
            from Inventory
            where {0} like @searchKey Order By ID asc;", value);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchKey", txtSearch.Text.ToString() + "%");
        OleDbDataAdapter adp= new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //adp.Fill(ds);
        //DGVinventory.DataSource = ds;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        DGVinventory.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        con.Close();
    }
}

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchData();
}
```

Comment: Instead of reposting your question you should edit the former with the code changes; the edit history will reflect older versions if anyone is that interested. That aside, you should show the rest of the code in your TextBox changed event; because it sounds like you're adding those columns manually before calling `searchData`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Search using ComboBox and Textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893035/c-sharp-search-using-combobox-and-textbox)